# mysqld error - mysqld.exe has stopped working

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, innodb

have following issue after voltage jump today when I'm tring to start sql server..

```
12:46:46 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 133760 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
1372780    mysqld.exe!my_thread_name()
15a56bd    mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
14c4010    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
14c481d    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
14250ee    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
14b9141    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
14b957f    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
141394d    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
1413b76    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
1413e72    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
13fe0ac    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
13e796e    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
13a28fa    mysqld.exe!xor_string()
1129990    mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
1162eae    mysqld.exe!?plugin_lock_by_name@@YAPAUst_plugin_int@@PAVTHD@@PBUst_mysql_lex_string@@H@Z()
1167354    mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
11211bd    mysqld.exe!?init_common_variables@@YAHXZ()
1121eb0    mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
1122417    mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
15a020a    mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
75a4495d    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
778c98ee    ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
778c98c4    ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I already run `mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=1` and drop all my tables, but an error wasn't solved. I only interested in normal sql running, can someone help? I'm using xampp 3.2.1 on windows 8, mysql version - 14.14 Distrib 5.6.11 for x86.

Comment: what version of mysqld is that?

Comment: 14.14 Distrib 5.6.11 for x86

Comment: same problem win8, x64, 5.6.22